# How to identify a specific XML element without ID attributes

Tags: python, xml

I'm working with XML documents that have many `<text>` elements. But none of them have IDs or any other attribute--just the element tag.  Is there any way I can use python to tell one of these elements from another (other than by the contents)?  For example do elements have some inherent index number based on their position in the document or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have lxml ElementTree, and you want to get details for a particular element:

```
>>> element
<Element e at 0x7f71068abf38>
```

You can find index of element inside parent and full path of element:

```
>>> element.getparent().index(element)
0
>>> element.getroottree().getpath(element)
'/root/e[1]'
```

That's all you have. For more sophisticated info (such as "global index" of element in the whole document) you should write custom code.

Comment: what is `0x7f71068abf38`?

Comment: Just a random number that identify an object in memory